# TryUpdateModelAsync() can't pass in object parameters to update

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model

I am having the strangest issue. I am trying to update a model's properties, like so:

```
        Answer = await dbContext.Answer.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ID == postedAnswer.AnswerID);

        // Set timestamp and answer
        Answer.AnswerTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
        Answer.SelectedAnswer = postedAnswer.SelectedAnswer;

        //Save changes
        await TryUpdateModelAsync(
            Answer,
            "Answer",
            p => p.AnswerTimeStamp, p.SelectedAnswer);

        // Save changes
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

However, intellisense is throwing an error on p.AnswerTimeStamp:
"Answer does not contain a definition for AnswerTimeStamp and no extension method bla bla bla..."

One of the versions of TryUpdateModelAsync allows for passing in the model, a string name, and the parameters to update. In fact, I use the exact, VERBATIM, code in another Page, except with a different model with the same properties and it works there.

What is going on? This refuses to build

See this screenshot:

[image: Problem]

Intellisense recognizes that "p" is of type Answer, but no properties will show up when I begin typing them.

Comment: try await TryUpdateModelAsync<Answer>(Answer, "Answer", p => p.AnswerTimeStamp, p.SelectedAnswer);

Comment: @RajN I have tried this as well. Intellisense seems to recognize that "p" is of type Answer, but no related properties show up when I begin typing the property. See this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/YD8hv

Comment: Maybe because you named the variable as Answer. try changing it to something as 'answer' and see if it works.

Comment: @RajN Interestingly that appears to work. The type is "Answer" so I changed the object name to "Answer_Test" and suddenly it worked. What is strange though is on another Page I do the same thing with a type "Survey" where the object is also named "Survey" and it works fine there...

Comment: Glad, it worked, Best practice and avoid this type of issues, avoid naming variable names as class names

Answer (score 2):

It is because IntelliSense is offering you different overload. `TryUpdateModelAsync<TModel>(TModel, String, Func<ModelMetadata,Boolean>)` instead of `TryUpdateModelAsync<TModel>(TModel, String, Expression<Func<TModel,Object>>[])`. You may want to explicitly say you want to use the one with includeExpressions parameter.

```
await TryUpdateModelAsync(
            Answer,
            "Answer",
            includeExpressions: p => new [] { p.AnswerTimeStamp, p.SelectedAnswer });
```

Related links:

[TryUpdateModelAsync[TModel](TModel, String, Func[ModelMetadata, Boolean])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.tryupdatemodelasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_TryUpdateModelAsync__1___0_System_String_System_Func_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ModelBinding_ModelMetadata_System_Boolean__)

[TryUpdateModelAsync[TModel](TModel, String, Expression[Func[TModel,Object]])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.tryupdatemodelasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_TryUpdateModelAsync__1___0_System_String_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Object_____)

Comment: This works but only for the first parameter. The second parameter shows "Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified"

I suppose this is because the comma in between makes this think I am adding a new parameter to the method? I have tried also adding p => p to the p.SelectedAnswer

Comment: Yes, it is expecting array of objects. I didn't noticed yesterday. Try to use `p => new [ p.AnswerTimeStamp, p.SelectedAnswer ]` and let me know. I will update the answer.